# Fragment layout is not scrolling above keyboard when soft keyboard pop ups

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one fragment whose layout i want to show above keyboard when softkeyboard opens up. The layout is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_splash"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/previous"
                        android:layout_width="37.5dp"
                        android:layout_height="37.5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/left"
                        android:padding="7dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/subCat"
                                android:layout_width="157.5dp"
                                android:layout_height="157.5dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="@string/enter_answer"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="13sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="262.5dp"
                        android:layout_height="52.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/answer_bg"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/answer"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="8"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
                            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:padding="7dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/wrong_answer"
                            android:layout_width="27.5dp"
                            android:layout_height="28dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/red_cross"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/reset"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
                            android:text="@string/reset"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="14.3sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/submit_ans"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                            android:paddingLeft="17dp"
                            android:paddingTop="7dp"
                            android:paddingRight="17dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                            android:text="@string/submit"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/lineColor"
                            android:textSize="14.3sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/next"
                        android:layout_width="37.5dp"
                        android:layout_height="37.5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/right" />

                </RelativeLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/write_dark"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#70000000"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/write_success"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:elevation="10dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried by setting windowssoftinputmode to adjustResize in manifest and also using fitsystemwindows to true in the fragment parent layout but still it is not working and using scrollview as parent layout instead of relativelayout. So please suggest me any workaround for this issue.

Edit: Added below activity.xml layout:
Below is the host activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/language_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_rounded">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/taskBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="143dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/hello_logo" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/learn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="33dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/learn_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/learn"
                        android:textColor="@color/lineColor"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/learn_bar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lineColor" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/practice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="42dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/practice_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/practice"
                        android:textColor="@color/lineColor"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/practice_bar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lineColor"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.3"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/unlock"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="26.5dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/unlock_blue" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/unlock"
                        android:textColor="@color/lineColor"
                        android:textSize="11dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/language"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="33dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/language" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/language_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/lang"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/lineColor"
                        android:textSize="11dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_practice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/read_mode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="23.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="17.5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_read" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                    android:text="@string/read"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/read_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/speak_mode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="16.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="21.5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_speak" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                    android:text="@string/speak"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/speak_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listen_mode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="18.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="18.5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_listen" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                    android:text="@string/listen"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/listen_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/write_mode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="17dp"
                    android:layout_height="19dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_write" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                    android:text="@string/write"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/write_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to get scrolling behavior, use `ScrollView` as root or parent.

Comment: i was using that but it was too not working

Comment: How did you use the `ScrollView`? Can you provide it?

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA I have edited the question, please check!

Comment: Remove fill viewport?

Comment: @user3875913 But i have to show the layout at center of the screen and without fillviewport it will be displayed on top of the screen

Comment: I have tried your xml, I don't get the layout. The layouts all on top and crossed to the right edge at the preview. Do you have a preview what you want achieve?

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA Just added images please check.

Comment: Maybe try to add one more `RelativeLayout` before `ScrollView`, so `RelativeLayout` is now the parent. Then add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in the `ScrollView`. It make your `ScrollView` to be at center and should be adjustable by keyboard.

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA Tried but still not working :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After commenting this from my activity onCreate() it started working:

```
    this.getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your scrollView into  relative Layout.